# Jedis Connect To Redis Using SSH Tunneling

Tags: java, redis, jedis

How can I connect to Redis using jedis by using an SSH tunnel?

I tried using

```java
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("ssh://sshuser:[sshpassword]@sshhost:sshport");
```

but this only resulted in the error "Unknown reply: S".

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("rediss://sshuser:[sshpassword]@sshhost:sshport");
```